# WPF C# OpenFileDialog does not show Network Storage

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, networking, openfiledialog

At the moment i am working on a C# WPF-Project. It uses the Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog and the System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog, which both work as expected except for the following problem:

They both do not show my Networkdrives!
While the default Windows explorer (Win 8.1 btw.) and the OpenFileDialog in an older Winforms-Project do show all the devices, the WPF Application only shows local drives.
I have no Idea why this happens and how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your application run with elevated permissions? If so have a look at this [MDSN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f0073f80-cedb-4b7a-96b9-20e4b22c2424/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8) post

Comment: @BerndLine this was actually very helpful... i wonder why i did not find that post in my research :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this happens when the application runs with elevated permissions like bernd commented on my question.

Look at this [MSDN Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f0073f80-cedb-4b7a-96b9-20e4b22c2424/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8) for all the details.

Comment: i wonder why the applications seems to have less rights (in this case) when it launches with elevated permissions. on the other hand i dont know anithing about priveliges here :D